# Deque class using typing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, type-safety

I wanted to make a class for type hinting that the result of a function is a homogenous deque.

```
from typing import MutableSequence, T, _geqv
from collections import deque

class Deque(deque, MutableSequence[T], extra=deque):
    """A typing-like type for use with function signatures using deque's."""
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        if _geqv(cls, Deque):
            raise TypeError("Type Deque cannot be instantiated; "
                            "use deque() instead")
        return deque.__new__(cls, *args, **kwds)
```

I basically copied the structure of similar code in the typing module. My question is, is this the correct way to do this?